# Is it possible to loop within a placeholder over the plugins?

Tags: django-cms

I would like to know how many plugins are attached to a certain placeholder.
Is this possible within a template?

Thanks,
Niels

DjangoCMS 2.4

Answer (score 1):

Placeholder instances have two methods that can help with this:

`get_plugins` and `get_plugins_list`

from a template you can do the following:

```
{% with total_plugins=placeholder_instance.get_plugins.count %}
<p>There's {{ total_plugins }} here !!!</p>
{% endwith %}
```

OR

```
{% with total_plugins=placeholder_instance.get_plugins_list|length %}
<p>There's {{ total_plugins }} here !!!</p>
{% endwith %}
```

the difference being that `get_plugins` returns a queryset and `get_plugins_list` returns a list so if you plan on iterating over these plugins, I would recommend `get_plugins_list` so you only hit the db once, otherwise `get_plugins` is more efficient if you just want a count.

Comment: How should I implement this? I'm missing a bit of context. I tried :{% with total_plugins=placeholder_instance.get_plugins.count %}
{% placeholder gallery %}
<p>There's {{ total_plugins }} here !!!</p>
{% endwith %}

Comment: where are you trying to implement this ? meaning are you doing this from a plugin template or just a normal template rendered by a normal view ?

Comment: In a normal (django) template.

Comment: could you post the template ?

Comment: I've made an example what I am trying to do.  I don't want to change the HTML structure.  http://pastebin.com/FZGLui63